# what does "shout cat calls at me" mean?

Tags: meaning

Maybe I know nothing about english and this is too easy phrase, but can you tell me what does "*shout cat calls at me*" mean?
**In context:**

> I pulled my shoulders back and tried to look confident, not letting
>   the nerves show on my face. As if on cue, the boys started to whistle
>   and shout cat calls at me, and the girls stared at me with a mixture
>   of jealousy and hatred. Looks like I’m not going to fit in here very
>   well after all…

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=cat+calls

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A "cat call" is a term for the noises and words that people might call out when an attractive person is walking by. The most common kind has another name, [wolf whistle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf-whistling), which has a very specific sound (there is an audio clip on the linked page).

In context, the person is saying that she is going to have a lot of boys calling out to her when she walks by because they think she is attractive and are trying to get her attention.

Catcalling is regarded by most people as very rude, so if someone's behavior is described as catcalling, it's usually meant in a negative or derogatory sense.

Comment: +1 - This is essentially the equivalent of someone yelling "Hey everyone, come watch this hot chick walk by!" loud enough for even her to hear. So now the mundane and essential act of locomotion has been turned (against her will) into a performance. Often the guys will yell their assessments of the performance too. Its beyond rude, which is why it is typically done by men in difficult to reach spots, like high-rise construction workers or from moving cars.